# Custom functions with start and end

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I was looking at some module of Laravel with User permission where we can use something like

```
@permission
  {{ some blade code}} and some mark up 
@endpermission
```

I find it very intuitive... something like has @permission(['perm1', 'perm2']) will make a good authentication system and also can be used in many different ways.

Can some one let me know how to go about this? I know how to make a helper and then access function like

```
{{ myfunction() }}
```

but how to get that with @ is something I want to know.

Comment: Follow this documentation to extend blade. [Extending Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#extending-blade)

Comment: [This article](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/custom-conditionals-with-laravels-blade-directives) might also help.

Comment: @Bogdan yes the article is very helpful and I am going to try this thing now. Seems quite straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

This is already native for Laravel. Consider the following snippet:

```
@can('update-post', $post)
    <a href="/post/{{ $post->id }}/edit">Edit Post</a>
@endcan
```

You have to study the `Authorization` service:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization